# Why are my Portal Users sharing their usernamespace with the world in Spring '13?

Tags: customer-portal, user-management, bug, api-27, hvpu

At the same time as the rollout of Spring '13, I'm encountering issues related to High Volume Customer Portal Users: their usernames are now clashing with users in **other orgs**.

I'm aware that Portal Users are *almost* first class citizens: they have Session Ids, can perform JavaScript Remoting, can be given permission to make API calls etc, *but*:

- they must login via a special page identifying the target Org and Portal,
- usernames/emails can be changed at will without requiring verification,

However I was [confident](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/3747/320) that those usernames only had to be unique within **my org**.

I don't recall seeing this change in the Spring '13 release notes. Can anyone offer guidance? Is this a side effect of the impending release of Chatter Communities?

Edit: what drew me to identify the namespace clash was that I couldn't modify a High Volume Customer Portal User without changing his username first, *which was then impossible to change back because it was the same as a non-portal user in another org*. You too can sanity check this: try to create a High Volume Customer Portal User with username `derp@demo99.com` in a **Spring '13 org**.

**Edit1: raised a case with Salesforce; they reproduced the issue on separate internal test orgs and escalated straight up to R&D. Support from these guys is *outstanding*. I'll keep you updated.**

**Edit2: Salesforce have confirmed this is a regression and that they will be releasing a fix for this. Couldn't have asked for a better sanity check than the testing you guys did. Sincere thanks to all.**

**Edit3: this has been patched by Salesforce in very good time and transparently throughout the process. Portal usernames per-org are restored.**

[image: dev org clash]

Comment: Could you provide a bit more detail in your question about how you've identified that you had user accounts which clashed with another org? (as opposed to within your own org)

Comment: Are you 100% sure you don't have that user in your org?

Comment: I panicked a little reading this. I tried creating a user with the username you provided and it was fine. Do you have just one org? Are you sure you do not have another user with this name?

Comment: Thanks kindly for testing @RichardN. Are you on Spring '13 or (possible red herring) Chatter Communities pilot? The `derp@demo99.com` user was created in a different (dev) org specifically to test that conflict, I'm 100% sure :-(

Comment: I tested with a Winter13 DE sandbox and it worked (as you expect). I then created a partner org and unfortunately it didn't provide me the ability to specify the version I was interested in and it was created in Winter12 also... so, I can't yet test this further myself. When you click the 'View Users' button when viewing the High Volume Customer Portal profile, does it show another user with that username in the list?

Comment: @Markpond sincerely appreciate your persistence. I've reconfirmed that username is not in the list. Queried for it in Developer Console, triple checked I'm logged into the correct org in an incognito window, pinched myself...

Comment: @user31 - I can confirm that this is happening for me on my Winter '13 DE (na14).  I can create a portal user in my org with `derp@demo99.com` as the username, but I cannot create a portal username that has the same username as one of the regular names in my org, and I cannot create a regular user that has the same username as one of my portal users.  FYI: I don't have a lot of users in my DE, so I can just view all of them in a users list view easily.

Comment: @user31 - I also am able to create portal users in my one Winter '13 DE that have the same user name as users in my other Winter '13 DE.

Comment: Grateful to @PeterKnolle for trying in WI13. This behaviour (normal usernames vs portal usernames in same org) I'm familiar with. Just tried again; cannot edit a SP13 Portal User in Org A to have the same username as WI13 System Administrator in Org B.

Comment: I can create a partner portal user in Spring '13 org with the username of 'derp@demo99.com' just fine.  I can also edit it to be different and edit it back again.  Sadly I don't have HVCP licenses in that org at the moment to check with that license type.

Comment: I should also add, if you have previously used that username before and it belongs to an inactive user, it cannot be used again.

Comment: I've reproduced the same behaviour as @StevenHerod. I don't have HVCP users either but I would be surprised if this behaves differently for high-volume vs. regular portal users.

Comment: I could make a HVCP licensed portal user with username: derp@demo99.com on a w13 sandbox.

Comment: My testing indicates that this issue is fixed. @user31 could you try it on your end?

Comment: roger that @metadaddy, this is fixed - woop woop!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [user320](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/320/user320) mentions in an update at the bottom of the question, this was a regression in Spring '13. Salesforce fixed the issue in a patch release during the week of Feb 11 2013.